# Query on usage of class TypeAndSize in Java

Tags: java, oop

As per the [assignment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68481/does-this-simulation-follow-abstraction-and-encapsulation) given in this on-line self learning [course](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/pj1/readme),

I would like to store `int hungerLevel` & `int starvationTime` only for `Shark`  in below `TypeAndSize` class, but not for `Fish` or `Empty`.

```
class TypeAndSize {

  int type;                   // runType EMPTY, SHARK, or FISH
  int size;                   // Number of cells in the run for that runType.

  public static short EMPTY = 0;
  public static short SHARK = 1;
  public static short FISH  = 2;
  /**
   *  Constructor for a TypeAndSize of specified species and run length.
   *  @param species is Ocean.EMPTY, Ocean.SHARK, or Ocean.FISH.
   *  @param runLength is the number of identical cells in this run.
   *  @return the newly constructed Critter.
   */

  TypeAndSize(int species, int runLength) {
    if ((species != TypeAndSize.EMPTY) && 
            (species != TypeAndSize.FISH) &&
                        (species != TypeAndSize.SHARK)) {   
      System.out.println("TypeAndSize Error:  Illegal species.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    if (runLength < 1) {
      System.out.println("TypeAndSize Error:  runLength must be at least 1.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    this.type = species;
    this.size = runLength;
  }

}
```

My question:

Syntactically, Does Java allow you to  declare these two members only for `Shark` in `TypeAndSize` class,?

Note: I am new to Java programming.

Comment: You should extend TypeAndSize. Add the two new fields only to the extending class. btw. for the species you should use an enumeration instead of static short fields

Comment: @Michael what could be the name of extended class? for every new creature that i add with special property, I would need to extend? because TypeAndSize is only used for datastorage. I guess Every class in java cannot be an abstraction, this is one example.

Comment: your example with fish is not too good, to explain inheritance but basically: Your TypeAndSize should be called SeaDweller. It has a type and a size ok! then you can extend this class: Fish extends SeaDweller. The "Fish" class could have a new field like "numberOfFins". Also possible: Crab extends SeaDweller, and the crab has a field called "numberOfLegs". Then you could have something like Shark extends Fish. And the Shark class would have the additional field hungerLevel and starvationTime.

Comment: @Michael Please do no get into my code design given in assignment link. `TypeAndSize` class has no link with `Fish` or `Shark` class. It is used by `RunLengthEncoding` class.

Comment: ok now I see where this is going. In this case I would add the two fields in the TypeAndSize class and just not use them, if the type is not "shark"

Comment: @Michael This is an answer for which i would not need to raise query. When i create an object of type `TypeAndSize` class for every runType, these two fields will take extra memory, which is not good. i think in C, we have feature to include special members in a structure based on conditions.

Comment: This is not possible in java. If your application gets critical on memory, I'd extend TypeAndSize. From what I read in the assignment, I'd implement "Shark extends TypeAndSize" as only the shark can have those two extra fields. But this way, you will have to do some casting when processing the ocean.

Comment: @Michael Another point `enum` is used for compile time checking and avoid errors while passing invalid constants. So, in my static declarations, i already assigned values, which i will make it `final static`.

Comment: The constructor call would be a little safer with enum instead of just int and you would get rid of a few comparisons.

Comment: @Michael in the sense?

Comment: With a enum like enum Species {empty,fish,shark} your constructor would be: TypeAndSize(Species species, int runLength) { if species==null error ...

Comment: But the declaration in `DListNode2` class constructor will change to `DListNode2(TypeAndSize.Species runType, int runLength) {` which is awkward.

Comment: I did not dive that deep into the code :) But I your initial question should be answered